# Amplify/React AppSync graphql subscriptions @auth error

Tags: graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, react-typescript

Hello there :slight_smile:

I've a little problem related with the @auth.
(Amplify + React + AppSync)

#### schema.graphql

```
type Ticket @model
@auth(rules: [
  {allow: owner, provider: userPools},
])
{
  id: ID!
  status: String!
  owner: String!
  description: String!
}
```

#### build -> schema.graphql

```
type Subscription {
  onCreateTicket(owner: String!): Ticket @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createTicket"])
  onUpdateTicket(owner: String!): Ticket @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateTicket"])
  onDeleteTicket(owner: String!): Ticket @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteTicket"])
}
```

All operations (create update etc.) are working fine:

```
const {data: {listTickets: {items: items, nextToken}}} = await API
                .graphql(graphqlOperation(listTickets, {
                    owner: user.username                    
                })) as GraphQLResult;
```

**except** with subscriptions:

```
const subClient = API
  .graphql(graphqlOperation(onUpdateTicket, {
                    owner: user.username
})) as Observable<object>;    

subscription = subClient.subscribe({
                next: (data: any) => console.log('subscription data:', data),
                error: error => console.warn('subscription error: ', error)
            });
```

The subscription never trigger.
(No errors, no warnings)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

It was working!!!
I forgot to check "owner" not only in the input* but also in the fields below.

#aws-amplify-devs Could you please add this info to the documentation? :)
Could save many hours.